# Linked List pushback member function implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, push-back

I am a novice programmer and this is my second question on Stack Overflow.

I am trying to implement a pushback function for my Linked List by using a tail pointer. It seems straightforward enough, but I have a nagging feeling that I am forgetting something or that my logic is screwy. Linked Lists are hard!

Here is my code:

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(const T n)
{
Node *newNode;  // Points to a newly allocated node

// A new node is created and the value that was passed to the function is stored within.
newNode = new Node;
newNode->mData = n;
newNode->mNext = nullptr; 
newNode->mPrev = nullptr;

//If the list is empty, set head to point to the new node.
if (head == nullptr)
{
    head = newNode;
    if (tail == nullptr)
    {
        tail = head;
    }
}
else  // Else set tail to point to the new node.
    tail->mPrev = newNode;
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: First, if `head` is null, `tail` should also already be null, or something went horribly wrong. Second, if `tail` points to the last node in the list, shouldn't your `newNode->mPrev` point to *that* (`tail`), then set `tail = newNode;`?

Comment: Before writing any code, you should have drawn your linked list on paper, using boxes as the data and the lines between the boxes as links.  Then translate what you see on paper to code -- if you did that, clearly what you're doing seems to be wrong, as WhozCraig pointed out.

Comment: WhozCraig, you're absolutely right. My else statement should have been newNode-mPrev = tail. I knew I was making a stupid error! Paul, I did write some of it out on paper. I should have written it all out! Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @RyanSwanson yeah, but you never set `tail->mNext = newNode` in the case of a non-null `tail` (which you can infer from a non-null `head`), which is critical for this to work. See answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Your pointing the wrong `mPrev` to the wrong node. And you never set `mNext` of the prior `tail` node if it was non-null to continue the forward chain of your list.

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(const T n)
{
    Node *newNode;  // Points to a newly allocated node

    // A new node is created and the value that was passed to the function is stored within.
    newNode = new Node;
    newNode->mData = n;
    newNode->mNext = nullptr;
    newNode->mPrev = tail; // may be null, but that's ok.

    //If the list is empty, set head to point to the new node.
    if (head == nullptr)
        head = newNode;
    else
        tail->mNext = newNode; // if head is non-null, tail should be too
    tail = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, WhozCraig. Really helped me come to grips with this process.