# Need for 'back pointer' in linked List push back operation

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to figure out the following code to implement a `push_back` function for a linked list but I'm not quite sure why we need `back_ptr->next` and `back_ptr` to both point to `p`. I believe `back_ptr->next` could just point to `NULL` for it work, is there any advantage of implementing it as such that I'm missing?

```
void LinkedList::push_back(int element) {
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->element = elememt;
    p->next = 0;
    if (empty()) {
        front_ptr = back_ptr = p;
    } else {
        back_ptr->next = p;
        back_ptr = p;
    }
}
```

The following is the `LinkedList` class prototype. The `back_ptr` is being used to point to the end of the list for implementing the copy constructor (`push_back` makes it a lot easier to copy the list).

```
class LinkedList {
    void push_back(int element);
    // other member functions

    private:
    struct Node {
        Node *next;
        int element;
    };
    Node *front_ptr;
    Node *back_ptr;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linked List pushback member function implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606977/linked-list-pushback-member-function-implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cc
push_back(1);
push_back(2);
Node *p = new Node;
p->element = 3;
p->next = nullptr;
```

```
 front_ptr      back_ptr         p
     ↓             ↓             ↓
┌────┬────┐   ┌────┬────┐   ┌────┬────┐
| #1 |next| → | #2 |next|   | #3 |next| → nullptr
└────┴────┘   └────┴────┘↘  └────┴────┘
                          nullptr
```

```cc
back_ptr->next = p;
```

```
 front_ptr      back_ptr         p
     ↓             ↓             ↓
┌────┬────┐   ┌────┬────┐   ┌────┬────┐
| #1 |next| → | #2 |next| → | #3 |next| → nullptr
└────┴────┘   └────┴────┘   └────┴────┘
```

```cc
back_ptr = p;
```

```
 front_ptr             back_ptr  p
     ↓                         ↘ ↓
┌────┬────┐   ┌────┬────┐   ┌────┬────┐
| #1 |next| → | #2 |next| → | #3 |next| → nullptr
└────┴────┘   └────┴────┘   └────┴────┘
```

Comment: Just curious , how did you come up with the graphic

Comment: @AmitKumar I arranged Unicode block drawing characters and arrows manually. You can see the source in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42037632/revisions). (It's not very interesting.)

Comment: Wow the visuals make it a lot easier to understand. I guess I was missing the ordering of `back_ptr->next` and `back_ptr` updates (I thought they could have been written in any order). Thanks!

Comment: Next time, please use an actual graphic made in an image editor, do not use text art. It doesn't always look good on everyone's screen. A simple bitmap created in something like  MSPAINT would look much cleaner than what you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain if the list is not empty at the time of push back, the node which is currently tail should point its next to new node and finally tail should point to new node.

```
     Before push back 
     tail-> node x // tail points to node x
        x->next = null // as it is tail
     After push back new node y
       tail->next = y 
     As x was earlier pointed by tail ,this means x->next = p,
```

This step ensures the list remains connected.

```
     Finally , point the tail to the new node  
     tail -> y
```